Invertible matrix in $M_n(\mathbb Z)$

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$, and suppose that for all $X \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $\text{gcd}(X) = \text{gcd}(AX)$. I want to prove that $A$ is invertible in $M_n(\mathbb{Z}$).

My 1st attempt: Let $A = (C_1, \ldots, C_i, \ldots, C_n)$ with $C_i$ being the columns of $A$. Let $E_i$ be the vector formed of zeros except for the $i$-th entry, which is $1$. We have $\text{gcd}(E_i) = 1$, and thus by hypothesis, $\text{gcd}(AE_i) = 1$. Since $AE_i = C_i$, the columns of $A$ have a gcd equal to $1$. However, I do not know how to prove that this necessarily implies that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.
No, my reasoning is incorrect because one can have a matrix with the same columns with a gcd of 1.
Edit. As suggested by Anne Bauval, I am submitting my 2nd attempt as a response.

How do you define $\mathrm{gcd}$ of a zero vector? If the condition $\mathrm{gcd} (AX) = \mathrm{gcd} (X)$ implies that $(AX = 0 \Rightarrow X = 0)$, then linear independence of columns should be clear.

@Matsmir 1) Since (by definition) $\gcd(x_1,\dots,x_n)=d\iff\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle=\langle d\rangle$, $\gcd(\overrightarrow 0)=0$. 2) Linear independence of columns is not sufficient for invertibility in $M_n(\Bbb Z)$.

@AnneBauval 1) It is preferable that the OP clarifies definitions, not somebody else. It is not you who will decide on acceptance of the answers. 2) I am aware.

@Matsmir  I specified my definition of gcd and provided a possible proof, unless there are any mistakes.

@Noname I don't see any mistakes in the proof; nicely done! As for the definition, I see it in the question. My second comment was just a reaction on a surprising answer to my first comment (clarifying definitions) from some other person several hours after it was asked.

@Matsmir My comment was only for your personal information. This definition is standard.

@Noname After your edit, there is no question left in your post, and the accepted answer does not correspond to your implicit and new question "is my proof correct"? So, imo, you should roll back and post your second attempt as an answer (and - though it is easy to guess - define your $\alpha$).

Your steps 2 and 3 can be shortened as follows. Let $Z\in\Bbb Z^n$. There exists $Y\in\Bbb Q^n$ s.t. $AY=Z$. There exists $m\in\Bbb Z^*$ s.t.
$X:=mY\in\Bbb Z^n$. Since $AX=mZ$, we have $\gcd(X)=m\gcd(Z)$, hence $m\mid X$, i.e. $Y\in\Bbb Z^n$.

@AnneBauval  You are right, I will write my second attempt as a response, and I will use your shortcut

Since $A$ has integer entries, $A$ is invertible in $M_n(\mathbb Z)$ iff ${\det}(A)=\pm 1$, so it suffices to show that no prime $p$ divides ${\det}(A)$. Suppose by contradiction that a prime $p$ divides ${\det}(A)$, this means that $A$ is singular in ${\mathbb F}_p$, so that there is a a vector $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in{{\mathbb F}_p}^n$ with $AX=0$ in ${\mathbb F}_p$. Multiplying with a suitable scalar, we may assume that $1$ appears somewhere among the coordinates of $X$, at index $i$, say. Let $Y\in{\mathbb Z}=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ where $y_i=1$ and $y_j=x_j \ (\mod{p})$ for $j\neq i$.
Because of the value of $y_i$, we have $\gcd(Y)=1$. On the other hand, from $AX=0$ we deduce that $p$ divides all the coordinates of $AY$, so $p| \gcd(AY)$. Finally $\gcd(AY)\neq\gcd(Y)$, which finishes the proof.

Thank you, it's very clear.

Please, be more kind that the asker, confirm that the gcd of a vector is the gcd of all its entries.

@JeanMarie Confirmed (since you ask, though of course it is very hard to imagine how else one would define it). And I agree with Matsmir's comment that it is unclear how one would define the gcd of the zero vector. I would say that there are two choices, zero or "undefined". For both choices my proof works, as $1$ is different from both $0$ and "undefined".

As suggested by Anne Bauval, I am submitting my 2nd attempt as a response.
I use the following definition of the gcd of an integer vector: $\text{gcd}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = d \iff \langle x_1, \dots, x_n \rangle = \langle d \rangle $. Thus, $\text{gcd}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = 0$ iff $x_i = 0$ for all $i$.
First, I show that : $ A $ is Invertible over $\mathbb{Q}$
A matrix is invertible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if its determinant is non-zero, which is equivalent to its kernel being reduced to $\{0\}$.
Let $ X \in \mathcal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{Q}) $ be such that $ AX = 0 $. We can find $ m \in \mathbb{Z}^* $ such that $ mX \in \mathcal{M}_{n,1}(\mathbb{Z}) $. Let $ Y = mX $, then $ AY = 0 $, and hence:
$$
0 = \gcd(AY) = \gcd(Y)
$$
This would imply that $ Y $ is the zero vector, and consequently, $ X $ must also be the zero vector. Therefore, the kernel of $ A $ is reduced to the zero vector, making $ A $ invertible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Now, let's deduce that $A$ is invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $Z \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. There exists $Y \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ such that $AY = Z$. There exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}^*$ such that $X := mY \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Since $AX = mZ$, we have $\gcd(X) = m \cdot \gcd(Z)$, hence $m \mid X$, i.e., $Y \in \mathbb{Z}$.
